# Migrating Windows CE 5.0 user account credentials during update

Tags: windows-ce, credentials, ntlm

How are the credentials stored on a Windows CE 5.0 device? The user accounts are stored in the registry at [HKLM\Comm\Security\UserAccounts]. While it was possible with Windows CE 3.0 to copy the accounts from one registry to another this does not work anymore with Windows CE 5.0. Instead one have to register the credentails with NTLMSetUserInfo on each device.

I need to save the credentials, upgrade to the next version of the Windows CE 5.0 platform and restore the credentials. Unfortunately they are not valid anymore. Is there another way to store and/or migrate the credentials? The platform GUID at [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Windows CE Tools] is unchanged.